# connect a "public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver " to xml activity & call that

Tags: android

I want when my phone connect to the AC or USB show me a `Toast` but I can't use that, because I don't know how to call and don't know how attach them to xml activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent){

        int status = intent.getByteExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, (byte) -1);
        boolean usbcharge = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean accharge = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

        if (usbcharge) {
            // Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getAbortBroadcast(), "its a usb charger",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
            //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Toast.makeText(context, "connected to the usb charger", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (accharge) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "connected to the ac sharger", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "XML activity". You attach the Receiver from Activity Java code, and add the Receiver to the Manifest

Comment: i do that in manifest

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that and fix your code formatting

Answer (score 0):

please register your receiver in manifest file 
your broadcast receiver is Automatically Listen When USB of Adapter are connected.
so register your broadcast receiver in your manifest file like this

```
<receiver android:name="yourpackagename.MyReciever"></receiver>
```

[for more information about Broadcast receiver](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Comment: i add that before in manifest.in actually i cant use onCreate() to assigned xml Activity to java Activity.i don't have any idea for that.